# Display Desktopmonitor on multiple screens but with different content

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

Basically the idea is to have a powerpoint showing on the laptop (including an overlay timer) and this screen should be splitted into 2 different screens: 1 showing the exact duplicate of the desktop (including an overlayed timer) and another one should show the fullscreen ppt only.

I have tried with a vga-video-splitter but as the splitter only duplicates into multiple screens this wasn't the solution either.

Technically it would also work with an external videocard but I would prefer to try it without additional hardware.

Any ideas?

The solution with (virtual dimension found it in this board) seems to be a good idea.
However, I am looking for a way to display on 3 Screens with an laptop (different ports but dont know exactly what kind there are - need to have a closer look at work)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a DVI port on your laptop, I've seen adapters for DVI-out that caters for more than 2 output devices. you can look into that. It's cheaper than the vga-splitter... Hope this helps